# Retrieve image in img html control from oracle blob with VB or C#?

Tags: .net, oracle, blob, image, src

I have a webform application and I tried different ways for retrieving an blob image from Oracle but I couldn't.
I want to show the blob image in  `<img src="" />`
 on my .aspx.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I made a function which returns a  Byte()

```
Dim command As New OracleCommand("select photo from photoblob where id='1'", connection)
Dim reader As OracleDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
        If reader.Read Then
            Dim blob As OracleBlob = reader.GetOracleBlob(0)
            Dim byteArr As [Byte]() = New [Byte](blob.Length - 1) {}
            Dim i As Integer = blob.Read(byteArr, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(blob.Length))
            blob.Close()
            connection.Close()
                Return byteArr
        End If
```

And finally I used this code taken by http://bit.ly/YDlBvM to add the src to

```
Dim imageData As Byte() = functionReturnsByte()
Dim imageBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData)
Dim imageSrc As String = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64)
img.Attributes("src") = imageSrc
```

Sorry for being disordered. Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

Try this post.  It has your answer for how to get it into an Image object from the DB, and from there of course you just assign the image in your code behind.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/321ad2bf-6c83-4ac6-b6bb-e2b8472bea30

By the way, you won't use `<img src=""/>` in your .aspx, you'll use `<asp:Image ID="someImageID" runat="server"/>`, and then you can access your image by the ID in your code behind.  This isn't the only way to do it; I mean you could be using Razor or something and then you might do it differently, but it's one way to go about it.